# How to change the style of a specific site with a Tampermonkey script?

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Everytime I access a specific site like www.abc.com I want the background color to be red. How do I implement this condition in a tempermonkey script? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It would be probably easier with custom style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

In Tampermonkey the easiest way to change a style is to use the function `GM.addStyle`. Keep in mind you'll have to add the accordingly grant-tag in the header.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         change the style of a specific site
// @match        https://www.example.com/*
// @grant        GM.addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
GM.addStyle("body{background-color:red!important}");
```